# update a parameter in function block each timestep in simulink

Tags: matlab, for-loop, while-loop, simulink

I have the temperature (T) which should increase or decrease with a (delta_T) and it has an initial value of (T_0) and a (T_max = 100)
So, I defined (delta_T = 10 or an equation) and (T_0 = 20) and it should be a loop (T = T + delta_T) which updates the value of T each time step.
I will put this function in a block in Simulink.
I am expecting the results T will be equal 30 then 40, 50, etc until it reaches 100 and stop.
I tried for and while loop but failed
I hope my question is clear and many thanks in advance.

I have tried the following but failed to update T

```
function [delta_T,T] = fcn(u) 
m=100; 
T = 20; 
delta_T = u/m;
T_max = 100; 
while T <= T_max 
T = T + delta_T;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include your code in a MATLAB function block, it will execute the entire "while" loop each time step.

Change your function to

```
function [delta_T,T_out] = fcn(u, T_in) 
m=100; 
% T = 20; % Note that this line is commented out
delta_T = u/m;
T_max = 100; 
if T_in < T_max
    T_out = min(T_in + delta_T, T_max); 
else
    T_out = T_in;
end
```

See screenshots of the model and results below:

[image: Example model]

[image: Example results]

Comment: Thank you for your comment but it doesn;t update the T value. I got a constant output.

Comment: @AmeenMohamedBassam Please edit your original question to include the Simulink model

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The simulink model just include the function block with the mentioned code and a constant block with the input and two sink blocks with the outputs.

Comment: @AmeenMohamedBassam If the answer is satisfactory please mark it as accepted